# How do i create image background in gimp?

Tags: image, gradient, photoshop, gimp

I need to create splash screen for my mobile application and I want to use an image like the one I have attached with this question but with different color for splash screen.I guess this is a gradient but really don't know any idea how to create this type of gradient image with different color.Please help me providing any link or tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at

> http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/gimp-tool-blend.html
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjuCM-UTXaQ

for some gradient tutorials.

If you want the same image, with a different color, then just try changing the hue of your image like this

> http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-hue-saturation.html
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2ybYHxyxfQ

Comment: That for telling me about changing hue.It solved my problem :)